# Applying operators stored in a vector as text

Tags: r

I would like to apply operators stored in a vector `operatorsUsed` to `series1` and `series2` of the data frame `df`:

```
operatorsUsed = c('==', '>=', '<=')

series1 = 1:5
series2 = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5)

df = data.frame(series1,
                series2,
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I tried combining the `parse()` and `eval()` function:

```
nbrOperators  = length(operatorsUsed)

for (j in 1:nbrOperators){

  a            = df[eval(parse(text = paste0(df$series1, operatorsUsed[j], df$series2))),]
  tableCreated = paste0('b', j)
  assign(tableCreated, a)

}
```

But this doesn't work. With parse, I obtain for e.g. `j=1`

```
expression(1==1, 2==3, 3==2, 4==4, 5==5)
```

Which looks promising but then applying `eval` yields

```
[1] TRUE
```

Rather than the looked for

```
[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

Is there away I can apply operators stored in a vector as text?

Comment: `sapply(expression(1==1, 2==3, 3==2, 4==4, 5==5), eval)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` with `get`

```
lapply(operatorsUsed, function(op) get(op)(df$series1, df$series2))
#[[1]]
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

#[[2]]
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

#[[3]]
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

as @rawr mentioned in the comments, we can also use `match.fun(op)` instead of `get(op)` in the `lapply`

Comment: @akrun, thanks, with that I even get rid of my primitive loop :)